# Is there a ready-made formula to get Pitch/Roll values from iPhone 3GS's Accelerometer's X/Y/Z?

Tags: iphone, camera, accelerometer, angle, pitch

Just started to realize an augmented reality based project, got GPS location, heading, and the two missing variable to manipulate virtual camera is Pitch/Roll.

I'm wondering if there is a ready-made formula I can merge into the project. Could spare me a lot of time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got into the problem since, so a realy detailed post about the solution can be read here:

[Get pitch and roll angles from the iPhone's accelerometer vector](http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/archives/2010/06/15/Get_pitch_and_roll_angles_from_the_iPhones_accelerometer_vector/) at [gotoandplay.freeblog.hu](http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/)

Answer (score 2):

I think [this post](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/09/10/iphone-coding-using-the-accelerometer/) about the iphone accelerometer will answer most of your questions, including sample code.

Comment: Ohh, so simply pitch=acceleration.x, roll=acceleration.y. And the acceleration.z component tells me if the device is upside down somehow. Thisone will help me to create somehow the "360 degrees free camera". Thanks jilles.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the device rotation through the `CMMotionManager` which computes the radians based on raw data (accelerometer, gyro etc.). Make sure you enable the sensor updates:

```
if (motionMng.deviceMotionAvailable && !motionMng.deviceMotionActive) {
    motionMng.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 50.0;
    [motionMng startDeviceMotionUpdates];
}
```

Afterwards access rotation – `pitch`(x), `roll`(y) and `yaw`(z) – by querying the `attitude` object:

```
CMDeviceMotion *motion = [motionMng deviceMotion];

if (motion != NULL) {

    float pitch = motion.attitude.pitch;
    float roll = motion.attitude.roll;
    float yaw = motion.attitude.yaw;

    NSLog(@"ROTATION: x:%f y:%f z:%f", pitch, roll, yaw);
}
```